# Struct of bits in C

Tags: c, struct, bit

I have to store what values from the range 0-127 appear somewhere. 
So, I think to store it in type that it's size is 128 bits, so that if the bit is "turn on" the number appear, and if not the number is missing.
eg. if the first, sixth and nineties is 1, then the numbers 1,6,90 are appear.

How can I define by typedef type in c that contain 128 bits exactly?

Comment: you can use `char[16]` for 16*8=128 bits. no need of structure.

Comment: Try uint128_t from <stdint.h>. This is won't to exists on many systems though, so you will probably need to manually implement the bitfield through an array as a fallback

Comment: `char[16]` as @Dipto said and bit manipulation.

Comment: @doynax, does `uint128_t` exists?

Comment: @dipto: It depends on whether or not the compiler chooses to provide such a type. It isn't guaranteed, but then neither is uint64_t for that matter. As a rule of thumb you can probably expect it on 64-bit systems

Comment: @MrFox If `__int128` exists (and is what it says it is), then the most standard way to access it would be `int128_t`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, unfortunately not. gcc e.g implements `__int128_t` on 64 bit platforms, but doesn't list it in its extended types and doesn't provides `int128_t`, since otherwise they would have to adapt `intmax_t`, also.

Comment: `if the bit is "turn on" the number appear, and if not the number is missing. eg. if the first, sixth and nineties is 1, then the numbers 1,6,90 are appear.` How are you planning to do that exactly?

Comment: @JensGustedt That's bizarre, since I'd certainly expect `intmax_t` to be 128-bit if possible. It's just a recapitulation of folks hard-coding 16-bit `int` and whatever. GCC is extremely conservative, but perhaps they will adopt the standard interface eventually. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I'd suggest use `unsigned char[16]` which is more portable. As neither int128_t or __int128_t is standardized at the moment, use old school approach is safer IMHO.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, this is not extreme but just cautious. If you change `intmax_t` for an architecture, you change the ABI. All of a sudden, you wouldn't be able to link against older libraries. Interfaces that use `[u]intmax_t` are probably rare, but you never can be sure that there are no third party libraries that have this.

Comment: @JensGustedt ABI changes occur regularly. GCC is popular, and they have to sync with all the critical clients… I don't mean to suggest that their caution is unjustified.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, platform ABI changes? No, I don't think they occur often.

Comment: @JensGustedt They occur *regularly*, namely with language revisions that require breaking changes.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, ABI changes? What ABI changes did C99 or C11 induce? The ABI is not part of the language. API perhaps, though I am not aware of any. But not ABI.

Comment: @JensGustedt I was thinking of C++. Yes, you're right then.

Answer (score 2):

(The following solution is restricted to BSD systems like Mac OS X.)

You could use the bit-string manipulation macros from `<bitstring.h>`.
Example:

```
int numBits = 128;

bitstr_t mybits[bitstr_size(numBits)];
// Alternatively: dynamic allocation:
// bitstr_t *mybits = bit_alloc(numBits);

// Set bits:
bit_nclear(mybits, 0, numBits - 1);
bit_set(mybits, 1);
bit_set(mybits, 6);
bit_set(mybits, 90);

// Test bits:
for (int i = 0; i < numBits; i++) {
    if (bit_test(mybits, i)) {
        printf("%d ", i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does `<bitstring.h>` come from? It doesn't seem to be standard C11.

Comment: It is available on OS X. But when trying to find a reference I just noticed that it seems not to be portable, which makes my answer pretty useless … (Seems to be a BSD thing.)

Comment: It’s just a header file; it’s entirely possible that it will work elsewhere (with the caveat of potential differences in endianness – I will leave that as an exercise for the reader). It can be found here: [http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-825.40.1/include/bitstring.h?txt](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-825.40.1/include/bitstring.h?txt)